# Avconv video merging audio overlays

Tags: ubuntu, libav

I join 3 video files using **avconv** and create a intermediate file, using following syntax

```
cat inter1.mpg inter2.mpg inter3.mpg > interAll.mpg
```

**inter1.mpg,inter2.mpg** contains no audio track.

After create a  interAll.mpg I convert it to a **mov** file using following syntax

```
avconv -i interAll.mpg output.mov
```

My problem is, the audio track of inter3.mpg overlaying with video track of innter2.mpg in output.mov

Comment: How exactly is it "overlaying"? Does the audio track start too early? Is it distorted? Can you provide a sample video? Does this happen with all videos or just the ones you have? Finally, could you please post the full, uncut console output from avconv?

Comment: Ya audio track start it early... No its not destroyed. This happen with all video.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg now has the capability to concatenate files internally, you might have better luck with that. It works as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:inter1.mpeg\|inter2.mpeg\|inter3.mpeg" -c copy interALL.mpeg
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to remux them to mpeg transport stream files first:

```
for f in inter*.mpeg; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -f mpegts "${f/%mpeg/ts}"; done
```

Comment: he asked about avconv, not ffmpeg (which is obsolete btw)

Comment: @BЈовић FFmpeg is **not** obsolete. Don't trust the misleading message in the Ubuntu packages, which has [already been reworded accordingly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav/+bug/939863). FFmpeg is continually being developed (just see [their homepage](http://ffmpeg.org/)), and in fact, many features in Libav are just ported from FFmpeg, and vice-versa. For more info, see: [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115).